В pycharm библиотека импортирована, но в коде подчеркнута красной линией
Установил библиотеку selenium. При ее импорте в pycharm, она подчеркнута красной линией. Интерпретатор установлен верно, в установленных библиотеках интерпретатора она есть. При запуске код отрабатывает без ошибок. C другими установленными библиотеками поведение такое же  

попробуйте пересоздать проект в pycharm
